# separable measure algebra

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We now that any separable measure algebra $A_{\mu}$ with total mass equal to one, without any atoms, is isomorphic to the unit intervall with the lebesgue measure. This is a classical result of Charatheodory. What can we say if the measure algebra $A_{\mu}$ has atoms. Is it true that the measure algebra is isomorphic to a measure algebra generated by a measure space generated by the unit intervall, the Borel sigma algebra and some probabilty measure on it?

Comment: What if the space is countable? Say $\mathbb  N$ with counting measure.

Comment: Thank u , i have edited the question, we consider probabilty measures in this case

Comment: Take $\mu \{n\}=\frac 1 {2^{n}}$.

Comment: Is this a counterexample or what do u mean?